# Consuming apis with webclient

Tags: spring-webclient, couchbase-java-api

please help me how to create web client
My requirement is to develop middle ware services to consume existing APIs and database is postgres now my confusion is how to get data from postgres through consuming APIs and store the data to couchbase server that is my question

Comment: Hi! Do you need to make a one-time migration from postgress to Couchbase? or is it an app that will always be online? Could you please add more details to your question?

Comment: This is probably too broad of a question for StackOverflow. I would recommend narrowing it down a bit. That being said, take a look at the Couchgres project here: https://github.com/metonymic-smokey/couchgres/ and this blog post that covers the general principles of moving from relational to Couchbase: https://blog.couchbase.com/sql-to-nosql-automated-migration/